# Using Reflection to find [XmlAttribute("IWantThisValueRightHere")]

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with a few basic properties...

```
[XmlAttribute("MyFirstProperty")]
public string FirstProperty { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("MySecondProperty")]
public string SecondProperty { get; set; }
```

Using Reflection, I can enumerate through the public properties and get PropertyInfo objects for each of the properties above... the only thing I need now is a way to:

1. Detect whether or not the property has a XmlAttribute (I'm thinking this works via PropertyInfo.IsDefined(typeof(XmlAttribute), true) but would like to make sure)
2. Get the string value of the XmlAttribute

How is this done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 object[] attribs = myPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlAttribute),false);
 bool doesPropertyHaveAttrib =attribs.Length > 0; 
 string name = (XmlAttribute)(attribs[0].AttributeName);
```

Good point by Joel in the comments. My bad. Fixed.

Comment: You're going to have to do some casting on that last line. System.Object doesn't have an AttributeName property.

Comment: The easiest "fix" is to use Attribute[] attribs = Attribute.GetAttributes(myPropertyInfo, typeof(XmlAttribute));

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question. Stumbling upon the very same problem today, none of the solutions provided here worked. Especially seeing how the proposed solution `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlAttribute),false)`
throws an exception, because XmlAttribute isn't derived from System.Attribute. Instead you should check for `XmlAttributeAttribute`.

For future reference, this is the correct and working way to check for XmlAttribute using reflection:

```
PropertyInfo[] objProperties = obj.GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in objProperties)
{
Attribute[] propXmlAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(prop, typeof(XmlAttributeAttribute), false);
if (propXmlAttr.Length > 0)
     string myAttribute = propValue.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently use this approach:

'Get the properties

```
       Dim pi() As PropertyInfo = arguments.SourceObject.GetType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.GetProperty)
```

'get attributes for the properties

dim pitem As PropertyInfo=pi(0)

```
           Dim vobj() As Object = pitem.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(ValidationSettingsBaseAttribute), False)


          Dim attr As ValidationSettingsBaseAttribute= TryCast(vobj(0), ValidationSettingsBaseAttribute)
```